# Projeto não está cadastrando usuário, mas não apresenta erro de conexão ao Banco de Dados

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um projeto no Android Studio, onde uma parte é cadastrar um usuário, consegui fazer funcionar mas após dois testes de cadastro é apresentada a mensagem de cadastro concluída porém não aparece o registro no banco de dados e também não é apresentado nenhuma mensagem de erro no debug do Android Studio.

Segue o código:
Classe que gerencia a conexão:

```
public class DB extends _Default implements Runnable {

private Connection conn;
private String host = "10.0.2.2";
private String db = "airsoft_mobile";
private int port = 5432 ;
private String user = "postgres";
private String pass = "pgadmin";


public DB() {

    super();
    this.conecta();
    this.desconecta();

}

@Override
public void run() {

    try{

        //Realiza a Conexão com o Banco de Dados
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://10.0.2.2:5432/airsoft_mobile","postgres","pgadmin");

    } catch ( Exception e ){

        this._mensagem = e.getMessage();
        this._status = false;

    }
}

public void conecta(){

    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();

    try{

        thread.join();

    } catch ( Exception e ){

        this._mensagem = e.getMessage();
        this._status = false;

    }

}

private void desconecta(){

    if ( this.conn != null ) {

        try {

            this.conn.close();

        }catch (Exception e){

            this._status = false;
            this._mensagem = e.getMessage();

        } finally {

            this.conn = null ;

        }

    }

}

public ResultSet select ( String query ) {

    this.conecta();
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {

        resultSet = new ExecuteDB(this.conn, query).execute().get();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        this._mensagem = e.getMessage();
        this._status = false;

    }

    return resultSet;

}

public ResultSet execute ( String query ) {

    this.conecta();
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {

        resultSet = new ExecuteDB(this.conn, query).execute().get();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        this._mensagem = e.getMessage();
        this._status = false;

    }

    return resultSet;

}
```

}

A função responsável por adicionar o usuário que está dentro da classe Usuario.java:

```
public void adicionar_usuario() {

    String comando = "";

    if ( this.getId() == -1 ) {

        comando = String.format(    "INSERT INTO usuario (nome_usuario, email_usuario, nickname_usuario, " +
                                        "senha_usuario, data_nascimento_usuario, cpf_usuario, rg_usuario, " +
                                        "tipo_usuario, telefone ) " +
                                    "VALUES ( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' ) " ,
                                    this.getNome(), this.getEmail(), this.getNickname(), this.getSenha(), this.getData_nasc(), this.getCpf(), this.getRg(), this.getTipo_usuario(), this.getTelefone());
    }

    DB db = new DB();
    db.execute(comando);
    this._mensagem = db._mensagem;
    this._status = db._status;

}
```

A função responsavel por recolher os dados para adicionar os usuários:

```
private void adicionar(){

    String nome = txtNome.getText().toString();
    String cpf = txtCPF.getText().toString();
    String email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
    String telefone = txtTelefone.getText().toString();
    String nick = txtNick.getText().toString();
    String tipo_usuario = spnUsuario.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String senha = txtSenhaCadastro.getText().toString();
    String confirmaSenha = txtConfirmaSenha.getText().toString();

    if (! ( senha.equals(confirmaSenha) )) {

        Toast.makeText(ActCadastro.this, "As senhas não correspondem. Por favor digite novamente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txtSenhaCadastro.setText("");
        txtConfirmaSenha.setText("");

    }

    else {

        this.usuario.setNome(nome);
        this.usuario.setCpf(cpf);
        this.usuario.setEmail(email);
        this.usuario.setTelefone(telefone);
        this.usuario.setTipo_usuario(tipo_usuario);
        this.usuario.setNickname(nick);
        this.usuario.setSenha(senha);

        this.usuario.adicionar_usuario();

        Toast.makeText(ActCadastro.this, "Dados Cadastrados com Sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        if (tipo_usuario.equals("Sócio de Campo de Airsoft")) {

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(ActCadastro.this, ActCadastroCampo.class);
            i.putExtra("CPF", txtCPF.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);


        }

    }
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Qual lógica por trás disso: `if ( this.getId() == -1 ) {...`

Comment: @rubStackOverflow Pergunta pertinente!